# Send SYN packet in C#?

Tags: c#, networking, sockets

I am wondering whether it is even possible or I cannot do such a raw socket manipulation? If so, how can I try it? I am not trying  to do this old DoS attack, just curious how to send it thru C#.
Thanks

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to send raw packets using entirely managed code (you'd also need to be an administrator account).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this by creating a socket using `SocketType.Raw` and `ProtocolType.IP`options.

Then you can write the bytes that form the SYN packet to the socket.

Comment: Any idea How ? It's an interesting question